# Overridden Twig Templates Not Loading on Stage Site

Tags: timber

On my timber site I have a parent-child theme relationship. Both themes derive from the Timber Starter Theme repo. The child theme is enabled and has a single accordion twig file override just as a PoC.

Expected output looks like this:

[image]

Everything works great on my local machine (Lando/NGINX) but doesn't work on our stage site hosted in Platform.sh. For some for some reason, the accordion template is still coming from the parent:

[image]

I've dumped out the file locations in timber-library/LocationManager.php just to see and it seems to be loading the correct paths.

Has anyone run into this before? Is there something I'm missing in my stage site configuration to cause this?

Here are the repos:

Site Repo:
https://github.com/ColbyCommunications/libraries-site/tree/redesign

Parent Theme:
https://github.com/ColbyCommunications/colby-college-theme

Child Theme:
https://github.com/ColbyCommunications/colby-libraries-theme

Themes are pulled in through composer.